# Error en visual basic al imprimir DataGridView en pdf

Tags: vb.net, itextsharp

En el proyecto que estoy realizando en el cual tengo un datagridview del que exporto la info a un pdf y en este proceso tengo un error que no se porque no encuentra la referencia al datagridview, el error es l siguiente:

**System.NullReferenceException   HResult=0x80004003   Mensaje = Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.   Origen = <No se puede evaluar el origen de la excepción>Seguimiento de la pila: No se puede evaluar el seguimiento de la pila de excepciones>**

El codigo que utilizo para imprimir es el siguiente:

```
        SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
        If SaveFileDialog1.FileName = "" Then
            MsgBox("Introduzca el nombre de archivo para crear pdf!", vbExclamation)
        Else
            ExportData()
            MsgBox("Se ha creado corretamente", vbInformation)
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub ExportData()
        Dim parag As New Paragraph
        Dim doc As New Document(PageSize.A4, 40, 40, 40, 10)
        Dim writ As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, New FileStream(SaveFileDialog1.FileName + ".pdf", FileMode.Create))

        Dim font12Bold As New Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 8.0F, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK)
        Dim font12Normal As New Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 8.0F, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK)

        Dim pl As New Paragraph
        pl = New Paragraph(New Chunk("Afiliados: ", font12Bold))

        doc.Open()
        doc.Add(pl)

        Dim pdfTable As New PdfPTable(14)
        pdfTable.TotalWidth = 520.0F
        pdfTable.LockedWidth = True

        Dim widths As Single() = New Single() {0.3F, 1.0F, 2.0F, 1.0F, 1.0F, 1.0F, 1.0F, 0.3F, 0.3F, 0.3F, 0.3F, 0.3F, 0.3F, 0.3F}

        pdfTable.SetWidths(widths)
        pdfTable.HorizontalAlignment = 1
        pdfTable.SpacingBefore = 2.0F

        Dim pdfCell As PdfPCell

        pdfCell = New PdfPCell(New Phrase(New Chunk("NEmpleado", font12Bold)))
        pdfCell.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center
        pdfTable.AddCell(pdfCell)

        pdfCell = New PdfPCell(New Phrase(New Chunk("Apellidos", font12Bold)))
        pdfCell.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center
        pdfTable.AddCell(pdfCell)

        pdfCell = New PdfPCell(New Phrase(New Chunk("Nombre", font12Bold)))
        pdfCell.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center
        pdfTable.AddCell(pdfCell)

        pdfCell = New PdfPCell(New Phrase(New Chunk("Departamento", font12Bold)))
        pdfCell.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center
        pdfTable.AddCell(pdfCell)

        pdfCell = New PdfPCell(New Phrase(New Chunk("Telefono", font12Bold)))
        pdfCell.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center
        pdfTable.AddCell(pdfCell)

        pdfCell = New PdfPCell(New Phrase(New Chunk("Dni", font12Bold)))
        pdfCell.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center
        pdfTable.AddCell(pdfCell)

        pdfCell = New PdfPCell(New Phrase(New Chunk("Correo", font12Bold)))
        pdfCell.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center
        pdfTable.AddCell(pdfCell)

        pdfCell = New PdfPCell(New Phrase(New Chunk("Jubilacion", font12Bold)))
        pdfCell.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center
        pdfTable.AddCell(pdfCell)

        pdfCell = New PdfPCell(New Phrase(New Chunk("Seguro", font12Bold)))
        pdfCell.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center
        pdfTable.AddCell(pdfCell)

        pdfCell = New PdfPCell(New Phrase(New Chunk("ProtecDatos", font12Bold)))
        pdfCell.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center
        pdfTable.AddCell(pdfCell)

        pdfCell = New PdfPCell(New Phrase(New Chunk("PermisoImg", font12Bold)))
        pdfCell.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center
        pdfTable.AddCell(pdfCell)

        pdfCell = New PdfPCell(New Phrase(New Chunk("ABS", font12Bold)))
        pdfCell.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center
        pdfTable.AddCell(pdfCell)

        pdfCell = New PdfPCell(New Phrase(New Chunk("Afiliado", font12Bold)))
        pdfCell.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center
        pdfTable.AddCell(pdfCell)

        pdfCell = New PdfPCell(New Phrase(New Chunk("Img", font12Bold)))
        pdfCell.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center
        pdfTable.AddCell(pdfCell)

        Dim dt As DataTable = getDataTable()
        If dt IsNot Nothing Then
            For rows As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
                For colums As Integer = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
                    pdfCell = New PdfPCell(New Phrase(dt.Rows(rows)(colums).ToString, font12Normal))
                    pdfCell.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center
                    pdfTable.AddCell(pdfCell)
                Next
            Next
            doc.Add(pdfTable)
        End If
        doc.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Function getDataTable() As DataTable
        Dim dataTable As New DataTable("afiliado")
        Dim datacolumn0 As New DataColumn(DataGridView1.Columns(0).HeaderText.ToString, GetType(String))
        Dim datacolumn1 As New DataColumn(DataGridView1.Columns(1).HeaderText.ToString, GetType(String))
        Dim datacolumn2 As New DataColumn(DataGridView1.Columns(2).HeaderText.ToString, GetType(String))
        Dim datacolumn3 As New DataColumn(DataGridView1.Columns(3).HeaderText.ToString, GetType(String))
        Dim datacolumn4 As New DataColumn(DataGridView1.Columns(4).HeaderText.ToString, GetType(String))
        Dim datacolumn5 As New DataColumn(DataGridView1.Columns(5).HeaderText.ToString, GetType(String))
        Dim datacolumn6 As New DataColumn(DataGridView1.Columns(6).HeaderText.ToString, GetType(String))
        Dim datacolumn7 As New DataColumn(DataGridView1.Columns(7).HeaderText.ToString, GetType(String))
        Dim datacolumn8 As New DataColumn(DataGridView1.Columns(8).HeaderText.ToString, GetType(String))
        Dim datacolumn9 As New DataColumn(DataGridView1.Columns(9).HeaderText.ToString, GetType(String))
        Dim datacolumn10 As New DataColumn(DataGridView1.Columns(10).HeaderText.ToString, GetType(String))
        Dim datacolumn11 As New DataColumn(DataGridView1.Columns(11).HeaderText.ToString, GetType(String))
        Dim datacolumn12 As New DataColumn(DataGridView1.Columns(12).HeaderText.ToString, GetType(String))
        Dim datacolumn13 As New DataColumn(DataGridView1.Columns(13).HeaderText.ToString, GetType(String))

        dataTable.Columns.Add(datacolumn0)
        dataTable.Columns.Add(datacolumn1)
        dataTable.Columns.Add(datacolumn2)
        dataTable.Columns.Add(datacolumn3)
        dataTable.Columns.Add(datacolumn4)
        dataTable.Columns.Add(datacolumn5)
        dataTable.Columns.Add(datacolumn6)
        dataTable.Columns.Add(datacolumn7)
        dataTable.Columns.Add(datacolumn8)
        dataTable.Columns.Add(datacolumn9)
        dataTable.Columns.Add(datacolumn10)
        dataTable.Columns.Add(datacolumn11)
        dataTable.Columns.Add(datacolumn12)
        dataTable.Columns.Add(datacolumn13)

        Dim dataRow As DataRow
        For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
            dataRow = dataTable.NewRow()
            dataRow(DataGridView1.Columns(0).HeaderText.ToString) = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value.ToString
            dataRow(DataGridView1.Columns(1).HeaderText.ToString) = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value.ToString
            dataRow(DataGridView1.Columns(2).HeaderText.ToString) = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value.ToString
            dataRow(DataGridView1.Columns(3).HeaderText.ToString) = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value.ToString
            dataRow(DataGridView1.Columns(4).HeaderText.ToString) = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value.ToString
            dataRow(DataGridView1.Columns(5).HeaderText.ToString) = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value.ToString
            dataRow(DataGridView1.Columns(6).HeaderText.ToString) = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value.ToString
            dataRow(DataGridView1.Columns(7).HeaderText.ToString) = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(7).Value.ToString
            dataRow(DataGridView1.Columns(8).HeaderText.ToString) = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(8).Value.ToString
            dataRow(DataGridView1.Columns(9).HeaderText.ToString) = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(9).Value.ToString
            dataRow(DataGridView1.Columns(10).HeaderText.ToString) = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(10).Value.ToString
            dataRow(DataGridView1.Columns(11).HeaderText.ToString) = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(11).Value.ToString
            dataRow(DataGridView1.Columns(12).HeaderText.ToString) = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(12).Value.ToString
            dataRow(DataGridView1.Columns(13).HeaderText.ToString) = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(13).Value.ToString
            dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow)
        Next

        dataTable.AcceptChanges()
        Return dataTable
    End Function`



Gracias de antemano
```

Comment: Dónde ocurre el error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema lo tenía aquí:

```
 Dim dataRow As DataRow
        For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
            dataRow = dataTable.NewRow()
            dataRow(DataGridView1.Columns(0).HeaderText.ToString) = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value.ToString
            dataRow(DataGridView1.Columns(1).HeaderText.ToString) = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value.ToString
            dataRow(DataGridView1.Columns(2).HeaderText.ToString) = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value.ToString
            dataRow(DataGridView1.Columns(3).HeaderText.ToString) = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value.ToString
            dataRow(DataGridView1.Columns(4).HeaderText.ToString) = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value.ToString
            dataRow(DataGridView1.Columns(5).HeaderText.ToString) = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value.ToString
            dataRow(DataGridView1.Columns(6).HeaderText.ToString) = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value.ToString
            dataRow(DataGridView1.Columns(7).HeaderText.ToString) = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(7).Value.ToString
            dataRow(DataGridView1.Columns(8).HeaderText.ToString) = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(8).Value.ToString
            dataRow(DataGridView1.Columns(9).HeaderText.ToString) = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(9).Value.ToString
            dataRow(DataGridView1.Columns(10).HeaderText.ToString) = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(10).Value.ToString
            dataRow(DataGridView1.Columns(11).HeaderText.ToString) = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(11).Value.ToString
            dataRow(DataGridView1.Columns(12).HeaderText.ToString) = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(12).Value.ToString
            dataRow(DataGridView1.Columns(13).HeaderText.ToString) = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(13).Value.ToString
            dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow)
        Next
```

y lo solucione sacando el valor en vez de por la propiedad value por la propiedad EditedFormattedValue. Ejemplo:

```
dataRow(DataGridView1.Columns(13).HeaderText.ToString) = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(13).EditedFormattedValue.ToString
```